# Bootstrap menu blinks when clicking anchor link

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navigation

I have a bootstrap 3 menu. I've added: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` to the elements to force the menu to close on click in mobile view, to prevent it from taking up real estate and blocking the text on menu. It works beautifully.

In desktop view, however, when clicking on a menu item, it causes the menu to blink and reload. The blink occurs both on the server and in my local copy, but does not happen when I throw the code into codepen.

I've attempted to set it to only target the collapse on mobile, but I'm missing something.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="logo here" class="img-responsive logo" src="logo.png" /> </a></div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#welcome" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Welcome</a></li>
          <li><a href="#info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="#housing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Registration &amp; Housing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#security" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Security &amp; Transportation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">Agendas<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o">&nbsp;</i>Agenda 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o">&nbsp;</i>Agenda 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid --></nav>
```

CSS customizations on the nav:

```
.nav {
    font-size: 2em;
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    body {
    padding-top: 135px; }
.navbar {
    min-height: 125px;
}
}
.navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 40px 0 -15px;
}

/*Responsive font size on nav */
@media (max-width:1456px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
}

@media (max-width:1337px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
}

@media (max-width:1219px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
}

@media (max-width:1124px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
}

@media (max-width:1078px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1.15em;
}
}

@media (max-width:1053px) {
.nav {
    font-size: 1em;
}
}

@media (max-width:981px) {
.nav {
    font-size: .95em;
}
}

@media (max-width:959px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.navbar-nav {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
/*
.container > .navbar-header, .container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    min-height: 125px;
}*/
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none; }
    .logo {
        height: 42px;}
}

@media (max-width: 962px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-left, .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions you may have!

Comment: it happens in a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Y7iNGTgkSN.  Think what looks to be happening is it is causing your menu to collapse and then open again

Comment: Thanks! It's appreciated. It's really weird that I can't recreate the problem in codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting the `.navbar-collapse` with a link nested in the navbar itself, which evokes a blink everytime you click.

Remove all the `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` parts from your links, and add the following code:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

This will close the navbar when you click on one of the links inside the navbar. Note: this is a bootstrap 3.x solution. For bootstrap 2.x, add a click handler to the list items instead of the links:

```
$('.nav').click('li', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem that was the option on the navbar home had another event associated on it. So, when I was clicking on it all the navbar blinked. Thus, I added a id on my navbar and add a jquery block, as shown below:

HTML

```
<nav id="barraMenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                        data-target="#menuHorizontal" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menuHorizontal">
                    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

...

</nav>
```

JS - I added the if condition because it makes my hamburger menu works in @media situation that I have.

```
$("#barraMenu").click(function(e) {
   if (window.innerWidth > 753) {
      e.preventBubble();
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

I hope it can help someone. Thanks.